# Swift working with html-PDF

Tags: html, swift, pdf, export

I have a problem with export file from html to PDF. I can't find path to image. It doesn't show me.

This is my structure of files.

[image: Structure]

This is my code what I paste.

[image]

I will be thankful for everything.

Comment: by using just src ='logo.jpg' will not work in xcode. You need to be specify complete path here. eg. if my logo image in assets then the url should be like this src = 'assets/images/logo.jpg'

Comment: It doesn't work :( Image doesn't show.

Comment: Have you used assets for store an image ?

Comment: Yes i upload it to assets folder.

Comment: @DavidKadlcek try to convert image to base64 before  convert html to pdf

Comment: @a.masri OK I tried it, but it doesn't work. Can we start chat? I'll send u some images of code

Comment: @DavidKadlcek Ok

Comment: but i don't have enough reputation so u have to start chat :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171467/discussion-between-david-kadlcek-and-a-masri).